# Columns not aligning

Tags: html, css, alignment

Why are my Columns not aligning correctly? There seems to be a gap above.  Is there away that I can make them automatically set a width of the wrapper its in  `892px;`

http://jsfiddle.net/pJefg/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="leftColParts">
    Text Left
</div>
  <div class="rightColParts">
     Text Right
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.leftColParts{
    width:215px;
    background-color:red;
}
.rightColParts{
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    width:440px;
    clear:both;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: How should it be aligning?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pJefg/1/

Comment: The gap is the default 8px of margin applied to the `<body>` by most UA

Comment: It is not 100% clear what you want? Do you want both elements to be on the same line if there is space, with the second aligned to the right? If so you just need to set the first element to display: inline-block; http://jsfiddle.net/qRH9u/ and this example has a wrapper at 892px as you mention. As you can see it doesn't clear to a new line: http://jsfiddle.net/qRH9u/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

http://jsfiddle.net/pJefg/7/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
       <div class="leftColParts">Text Left</div><!--
    --><div class="rightColParts">Text Right</div>
<div>
```

--

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 892px;
}
.wrapper:after {
    clear:both;
    content: ".";
    height: 0;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.leftColParts {
    float:left;
    width:215px;
    background-color:red;
}
.rightColParts {
    float:right;
    width:440px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.leftColParts{
    width:215px;
    background-color:red;
    float: left;
}
.rightColParts{
    float: left;
    width:440px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Try this.

Alternatively this:

```
.leftColParts{
    width:215px;
    background-color:red;
    display: inline-block;
}
.rightColParts{
    display: inline-block;
    width:440px;
    clear:both;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the fiddle with what I think it is that you want.

What I've done:

- Floated both divs left
- Added a div with a clearfix (`clear: both;`)

You can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/pJefg/2/